# How do I pass the response writer and http request to an executable in Go?

Tags: go, exe

I want to run a simple webserver in Go doing some basic authorisation and routing to multiple apps.

Is it possible to have the webserver running as a standalone executable and pass the response writer and http request to other executables?

The idea is that the app binaries can hopefully be compiled and deployed independently of the webserver.

Comment: You're just writing a HTTP proxy. Ask yourself if you can write a better (faster, more functional, more secure) HTTP proxy than nginx or HAProxy.

Comment: This sounds like the old [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) or even [FastCGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) model.

Comment: Thanks lads. 
See my comments below regarding a proxy.
@maerics FastCGI looks like it might be a solution. Compiled Go might negate some of the downsides from back in the day with lower overheads.

Answer (score 3):

Memory areas of running applications are isolated: a process cannot just read or write another application's memory ([Wikipedia: Process isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_isolation)).

So just passing the response writer and the http request is not so easy. And even if you would implement it (e.g. serializing them into binary or text data, sending/passing them over somehow, and reconstructing them on the other side) serving an HTTP request in the background is more than just interacting with the [`ResponseWriter`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter) and [`Request`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) objects: it involves reading from and writing to the underlying TCP connection... so you would also have to "pass" the TCP connection or create a bridge between the real HTTP client and the application you forward to.

Another option would be to send a redirect back to the client ([HTTP `3xx` status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection)) after doing the authentication and routing logic. With this solution you could have authentication and certain routing logic implemented in your app, but you would lose further routing possibilities because further request would go directly to the designated host.

Essentially what you try to create is the functionality of a [proxy server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) which have plenty of implementations out there. Given the complexity of a good proxy server, it should not be feasible to reproduce one.

I suggest to either utilize an existing proxy server or "refactor" your architecture to avoid this kind of segmentation.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer icza.

Go does allow access to low level TCP functionality but I'm hoping I will not need to delve that deep if there is another solution out there.

Am I right in thinking that the proxy option would involve my destination apps listening on ports?
A HTTP redirect would certainly involve every app implementing a web listener.

@maerics mentioned FastCGI above. This seems to offer the functionality I need. My apps can receive input via TCP connection, Unix socket or the standard input. There is a Go package, fcgi, which implements the FastCGI protocol.

Comment: @rorstack Yes, using a proxy the applications would have to listen. But any solution you choose, the applications must listen or poll something in order to get notified of an incoming request.